# Problem with Inheritance in solidity . can not use any function from other smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I Have Two Smart contract , `DEXUserCoin` and `DEXTransferCoinUserToUser`.

I want to use Some Function from the `DEXUserCoin` into the `DEXTransferCoinUserToUser`.

**DEXUserCoin :**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import './DEXCoin.sol';

contract DEXUserCoin {

    struct UserCoin {
        uint coinId;
        uint256 amount; 
    }

    mapping(address => UserCoin) internal userCoins;

    constructor() {

    }

    function ApproveTransferSend(address userAddress , uint coinId , uint256 amount) external view returns(bool) {

        if(userCoins[userAddress].amount >= amount && userCoins[userAddress].coinId == coinId) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        } 

    }


}
```

in need to use `ApproveTransferSend` into the `DEXTransferCoinUserToUser` and i try this :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import './DEXUserCoin.sol';

contract DEXTransferCoinUserToUser {

    DEXUserCoin private desxUserCoin;

    constructor(){}

    function TransferUserToUser(address from , address to ,uint coinId ,  uint256 amount) 
    public view returns(bool) {

      return  desxUserCoin.ApproveTransferSend(from,coinId,amount);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just importing but not inheriting anything:

```
contract DEXTransferCoinUserToUser is DEXUserCoin {
}
```

or you have to set `desxUserCoin` value in constructor

```
constructor (DEXUserCoin _dex){
    desxUserCoin=_dex;

}
```

this constructor means when you create the contract, you have to pass a parameter to initalize the contract.